# Rails return single record using AR find

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to get back a single record using the following query:

```
Rating.where(recommendation_id:1773452, rating_set:18, product_id:2086981)
```

which returns:

```
 => [#<Rating id: 931, label: "Fair", rating: 2.0, created_at: "2013-02-21 22:20:19", updated_at: "2013-02-25 06:38:51", recommendation_id: 1773452, notes: "", rating_set: 18, product_id: 2086981, best_one: 1773452>]
```

I am trying to get a single attribute to show in my view. For example:

```
Rating.where(recommendation_id:rec.id, rating_set:params[:rating_set_id], product_id:params[:product_id]).pluck(:label)
```

which returns the value in quotes `["Fair"]`

How can I get back only the value `Fair`?

Comment: use `.first`. `Rating.where(...).first.label`

Comment: You can simply do as follow Rating.where(recommendation_id:1773452, rating_set:18, product_id:2086981).first.label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rating = Rating.where(recommendation_id:1773452, rating_set:18, product_id:2086981).first

rating.label # returns "Fair"
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. You can not directly get the value 'Fair'.

As Active Record will always return the object of the model. pluck is an additional helper that will bring the collection.

And when you query with `.where("CONDITIONS")` It will always return collection of objects.

So In that case you have to do the `.first.label`

My Suggestion is, if your conditions are going to be same then u can use `find_by` that will return single record.

`Rating.find_by_recommendation_id_and_rating_set_and_product_id(p1, p2, p3).label`